# swift viewcontroller showing proteced view for a second

Tags: ios, swift

I am having the issue that i have build a login script in xcode 6. But when people are not logged in you see the members area for a split second. I would like to hide it completely and only show those who are logged in. So i found this following code explaining that and how to do it. I adjusted the identifiers to reflect my viewcontrollers. This is the code that i have place in the appdelegate file.

this is the code

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        var isUserLoggedIn:Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")

        if(!isUserLoggedIn)
            {
                var loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginView") as! ViewController

                window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
                window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


        }else {
            var protectedPage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("memberView") as! ViewController

            window!.rootViewController = protectedPage
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
```

The problem is the i get use of undeclared type "LoginViewController"

```
var loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginView") as! LoginViewController
```

i have no idea why i always get this error when i just write it as they said in the tutorial, everything seems to be ok. This swift is much harder than php and i am very new to swift.

Can any one show me how to fix this or another solution to hide the protected viewcontroller.

Comment: Your 2nd code block says the type is LoginViewController but in your first code block it's just ViewController, which one is it?

Comment: Sorry that should be LoginViewController in both

Comment: any else with an idea of how to do this.

Comment: I have a similar functionality in one of my apps but I check if a user is logged in in the viewWillAppear method of my first view controller, then I send them someplace to login if they aren't logged in

Comment: but don't you see that protected page for just a second. that is what i try to  not have. It just is for looks, the app works perfectly.